# Database administration not accessible in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I am following the web2py tutorial and am trying to execute the example of creating an image blog in Chapter 3.3:

http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#An-image-blog

After having removed menu.py and having replaced db.py with the code

```
db = DAL("sqlite://storage.sqlite")

db.define_table('image',
                Field('title', unique=True),
                Field('file', 'upload'),
                format = '%(title)s')

db.define_table('post',
                Field('image_id', 'reference image'),
                Field('author'),
                Field('email'),
                Field('body', 'text'))

db.image.title.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, db.image.title)
db.post.image_id.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db.image.id, '%(title)s')
db.post.author.requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY()
db.post.email.requires = IS_EMAIL()
db.post.body.requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY()

db.post.image_id.writable = db.post.image_id.readable = False
```

, I am trying to access the database administration interface, but get an error ticket which starts with the following information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\Python lokal\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 219, in restricted
    exec(ccode, environment)
  File "c:/Users/username/Documents/Python lokal/web2py/applications/HB91_imageblog/views/appadmin.html", line 482, in <module>
NameError: name 'configuration' is not defined
```

I am not sure what I am missing, since I have exactly followed the tutorial.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the code shown is the one throwing the exception. Python is looking for a variable named 'configuration' and can't find it, but 'configuration' is not managed in the code shown.

Comment: I have started with a new application, and I tried this again with a second new application, just deleting menu.py and modifying db.py as described. So I do not think that I have defined that variable. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: Can you show the whole traceback? There is no "configuration" anywhere in appadmin.html.

Comment: Complete traceback here: https://storage.driveonweb.de/dowdoc/929c72cb4dc970c278779992ca318e73e49507a11f0efbe0

Comment: I can easily reproduce this error in different installations on different PCs. Just create a new application, delete menu.py and insert code above into db.py